# Categorizing and Classifying of Data in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, design-patterns

In my database, I have a table called `GroupValHeader`. In short this table has `GroupValCode`, `GroupValName`, and `GroupCode`. The purpose of this table is to categorize the data. Say I have a `Patient` table and a `Patient` can be `Regular`, `Corporate`, `Camp` and so on. So `GroupValHeader` would contain data like this

```
GroupValCode        GroupValName                            GroupCode
------------        ------------                            ---------
REGULAR             A Regular Patient                       PATIENTCAT
CORPORATE           A Corporate Patient                     PATIENTCAT
CAMP                A Camp Patient                          PATIENTCAT
GOVTHEALTHSCHEME    A Patient From the Govt Health Scheme   PATIENTCAT
RURALPATIENT        A Patient From Rural and Triabal areas  PATIENTCAT
POORPATIENT         A patient from lower income group       PATIENTCAT
```

The patient table has a foreign key relation with this table for establishing the patient category. Similarly have many tables have fk relation with `GroupValHeader` table.

I want to know what this pattern is called. Any search keywords that could help. Search on the net did not help, so please guide.

Comment: You may have to clarify your question - it isn't clear to me what "pattern" you are talking about. If you mean a table which decodes values (`GroupValCode`) into a description (`GroupValName`), then that would be a *Code Table* or a *Reference Data Table*.

Comment: It's an **anit-pattern** (one you *shouldn't* use!) called "Common Lookup Table" - see [this excellent article on Simple-Talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) about why to avoid this (and four other common SQL anti-patterns)

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks, thats what I am looking for. Also thanks for the article.

Comment: And the next question is what is the alternative. So the answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691580/why-is-using-a-common-lookup-table-to-restrict-the-status-of-entity-wrong